# Swagger not working on Azure Web app running as OWIN

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a ASP.NET Web API implemented as OWIN middleware. I hosted it on azure and now I have a problem using swagger. It is perfectly working on localhost but when I try it on azure I get this:

[image]

The way I did my configuration for swagger on the API was to completely remove SwaggerConfig.cs file and add all the configuration into my Startup.cs class as shown here: [How to generate documentation using swashbuckle for WebApi 2 with Owin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547983/how-to-generate-documentation-using-swashbuckle-for-webapi-2-with-owin) . If it is going to help, I am trying to implement oAuth2 between my API, identity server and client application.

Can you help me find out what is the reason for not getting swagger functionality on Azure?

EDIT: I also tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914842/swagger-ui-returns-500-after-deployment) but without success. I went to my API->Properties->Buld tab->Changed to 'Release' configuration->In the output path added the same what was in the 'Debug' configuration and nothing.

My bin folder on Azure:

[image: Here you can see that the xml resource file is there]

Comment: Do you require authentication to view the swagger ui? and can you browse to ../swagger/docs/v1?

Comment: No, there's no such requirement. When I run it on localhost there's no such thing as authorization. Right after I navigate to swagger/ui/index it gives me the controllers, methods etc.

Comment: can you browse to ../swagger/docs/v1?

Comment: No, when I browse it I get: <Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message></Error>

Comment: try setting <system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web> - then browse to swagger/docs/v1 and look at the error

Comment: I get exactly the same error. No matter if I have this set in my Web.config or not.

Comment: have you checked if the xml file is in the azure web server? use elmah to log the error, this is probably that swagger can't find the xml to generate the docs, user the server explorer Tab in VS to check for the file

Comment: @JGEstevez Yes, I can see it in the server explorer. It is there in the bin folder and has xml metadata inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself when going though [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/) tutorial.

In that tutorial on #3 under "Configure the middle tier to call the data tier" I named my key **apiAppURL** instead of **toDoListDataAPIURL**. This caused me to get 500 response codes and

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

in the response body.

I fixed it by updating the following line:

```
var client = new ApiApp(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toDoListApiURL"]));
```

to

```
var client = new ApiApp(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiAppURL"]));
```

**The change made was to the string at the end of the line. That code can be found in ToDoListController.cs on line 42

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Check your **SwaggerConfig.cs** file, if you are not included the xml file with your swagger, it works in your azure app services.

```
c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\bin\WebApiSwagger.XML");
c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
```

I've included these 2 lines of code to show my xml in the swagger, the azure swagger will gone error.

Answer (score 0):

This is late reply but may help someone in future.
I solved this issue this way:

1. Set XML documentation file path in project settings to : wwwroot\api.xml
2. Let Swagger know where the file is within ConfigureServices method in 
   Startup.cs:

   ```
           services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
       {
           c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

           // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
           var xmlFile = "api.xml";
           var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot", xmlFile);
           c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
       });
   ```

You can set different paths but you will get the idea of how to do it from this example.