# How to include class and property descriptions in Swashbuckle generated Swagger docs for WebApi 2 with OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, swagger, swashbuckle

Before you think of it, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547983/how-to-generate-documentation-using-swashbuckle-for-webapi-2-with-owin) is not the same.

I think this should be pretty much self explanatory. I would like to include class descriptions in the Swagger docs. My `Swagger` config looks like this:

```c#
config.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My Api Name");
    c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());

}).EnableSwaggerUi(c => { });
```

And `MyAwesomeController` looks like this:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Controller description (is included by Swashbuckle)
/// </summary>
public class MyAwesomeController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Method description (is included by Swashbuckle)
    /// </summary>
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("hello... from the other side");
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]MyAwesomeModel model)
    {
        return Ok("hello... from the other side");
    }
}
```

And my `MyAwesomeModel` looks like this:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// **I would like this to be included in the Swagger description of the parameter**
/// </summary>
public class MyAwesomeModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// **I would like this to be included in the Swagger description of the parameter**
    /// </summary>
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible without hiring Sr. Skeet?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Hm... so maybe if someone else runs into this.

Basically I found one way this can be done and I realized why it was not done by default. Not sure if it is the best approach but here it goes.

In my solution, the POCOs are located in a project separate to the actual API and thus, the comment description of `MyAwesomeModel` was not included because no XML nodes were generated for the classes and properties. So, in my separate project where the POCOs were located I modified properties to generate an XML.

1. Generate XML for project where POCOs are located

[image: Output XML for the project where model classes are located]

2. Make sure the XML is copied to whatever path you would like `Swashbuckle` to look for it. I used `Post-build event command line` in project properties;

`copy "$(SolutionDir)MyAwesomeProjectWithPocos\bin\MyAwesomeProjectWithPocos.xml" "$(ProjectDir)\bin\MyAwesomeProjectWithPocos.xml"`

[image: Post-build event to copy the XML file to the same bin folder as the API xml file]

3. Modify `SwaggerConfig` to include this XML as well

I.e.

```
config.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My Api Name");
    c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPathForModels());

}).EnableSwaggerUi(c => { });
```

Now, on the Swagger page, if I switch from `Model Schema` to `Model` I can now read the entire model and property descriptions.

[image: Click models to see model and property comments]

Naturally, there is no demand to copy the XML file, one may just point to the correct location in step #3 `GetXmlCommentsPathForModels());` but this was my option.

Comment: For me, it's not loading the `<summary>` for properties on my model unless it's a primitive type like `int`, `bool`, `string`, etc.  Did you run into this issue?

Comment: Honestly do not remember, this was in 2016.

Answer (score -1):

If you have put the below statement

```
c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
```

Can you check if the xml comment path method returns the path of the xml file where the Project XML Documentation file is placed?

Comment: The XML file exists and there is no problem with the generated comments which is default (Controller and Method documentation), but this is not what I am asking for - I also want to include the comments from the class definitions of the classes used as method input parameters. I don´t know how else to explain it.

Comment: Better post your request/issue in their Github website - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle